# OnClick() Function is not working in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, html-table

Below is my JSP code. I am having a function called AddData() in JavaScript.If i click Add button Data has to get inserted into the table. But when I click add button nothing happens. What‘s wrong with the code?I am new to java web application. What I need is When I click add button data has to be inserted into the table. If this is not the proper way let me know the other methods available.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Sales Order</title>
 </head>
   <body>
      <jsp:include page="_header.jsp"></jsp:include>
      <jsp:include page="_menu.jsp"></jsp:include>


        Select Item:
        <select id = "itmSpinner">
            <option value="0">Fluorescent Desk Lamp</option>
            <option value="1">13W Mini Fluorescent Bulb</option>
            <option value="2">Halogen Desk Light</option>
            <option value="3">50W/12V Halogen Bulb</option>
            <option value="4">Desk Note Book</option>
            <option value="5">Desk Calendar Pad</option>
            <option value="6">Bulletin Board</option>
            <option value="7">White Melamine Board</option>
            <option value="8">Dry-erase White Board Markers</option>
            <option value="9">Hanging File Folder</option>
            <option value="10">Letter Figuring Pads</option>
            <option value="11">Highlighter</option>
            <option value="12">Pen</option>
            <option value="13">Pencil</option>
            <option value="14">Calculator</option>
        </select> <br><br>

        Quantity :
        <input type="text" name="qty" id = "qty" /> <b><b><b>  <input id = "addBtn" type="submit" value= "Add" onclick = "AddData()"/>

        <table id = "itemTbl" cellspacing = "0px" cellpadding = "20px" text-align = "center">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>S.No</td>
                    <td>Item</td>
                    <td>Qty</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>

            </tbody>
        </table> 


 <jsp:include page="_footer.jsp"></jsp:include>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function AddData() {
        var itm = document.getElementById("itmSpinner").value;
        var qty = document.getElementById("qty").value;

        rows += "<tr><td>" + qty + "</td><td>" + itm + "</td><td>" + qty + "</td></tr>";
        $(rows).appendTo("#itemTbl tbody");
    }
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `rows += ` You don't have a `rows` variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use "rows" in your function but you forgot to define your variable. Change your function like this.

```
function AddData() {
    var itm = document.getElementById("itmSpinner").value;
    var qty = document.getElementById("qty").value;

    var rows += "<tr><td>" + qty + "</td><td>" + itm + "</td><td>" + qty + "</td></tr>";
    $(rows).appendTo("#itemTbl tbody");
}
```

Comment: Or simply do that: `var rows = "<tr><td>" + qty + "</td><td>" + itm + "</td><td>" + qty + "</td></tr>";`. No need to concat on empty string.

Comment: Thank you guys @sjahan & Mircea Andrei

Answer (score -1):

Please replace `type="submit"` with `type="button"` and try again. Hopefully it should work.

Comment: If a `type="submit"` is not in a form, it acts as a `type="button"`. It's not that.

Comment: May be put the function inside `$( document ).ready(function() {
   /* your function */
});`. Try this.

Comment: Defining a function inside a document ready callback would just remove it from global scope thus hiding it from the inline js attribute OP is using, `onclick="AddData()"`. Functions called directly in Inline js attributes must be in global scope.